# Prevent XSS attacks in WCF calls

Tags: c#, wcf, security, xss

I have a WCF service which has basicHttp endpoints exposed. The issue is reported in PEN testing that service accepts strings containing script tags and returns the strings with script tag which when directly used in web apps consuming it causes XSS attack.

What I can do is in every operation implementation write a code to make the strings script proof. But is there any easy/efficient way so that I can write a single code to clean all the incoming strings in WCF calls from script tags.

e.g. in AddUser operation which takes username and address, if I submit `Akshay<script>alert('hi');</script>`, the operation just should remove script tags.

So currently it is returning `Akshay<script>alert('hi');</script>` but is expected to return something like `Akshayalert('hi');`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own operation invoker:

```
public class CleanOperationInvoker:IOperationInvoker
{
    private readonly IOperationInvoker _invoker;
    public CacheOperationInvoker(IOperationInvoker invoker)
    {
        _invoker = invoker;
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        inputs = CleanInputs(inputs);
        return _invoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
    }

    private static object[] CleanInputs(object[] inputs)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.Length;i++)
        {
             var str = inputs[i] as string;
             if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                 inputs[i] = StripHTML(str);
        }
        return inputs;
    }

    public static string StripHTML(string input)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then implement behavior:

```
public class CleanOperationBehavior: Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        //Putting ourself in between dispatching invoker
        dispatchOperation.Invoker = new CleanOperationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker);
    }
}
```

Then just use it like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHackMeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [CleanOperationBehavior]
    int Get(string hack, string me, int beach);
}
```

Or you can implement endpoint behavior and attach it to all of your operations on all contracts. This way, by the way, you can even reject operation if it contains invalid strings. Just throw exception or something.

I has not compiled it, so if you meet any errors you can tell me and I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi eocron,
i have implemented your answer but i got two errors in "CleanOperationInvoker" class, errors are below.
1) CacheOperationInvoker : Method must have return type
2) a readonly field cannot be assigned to 

Could you please look into it and update your answer, i need it urgently.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi eocron, can you please provide me the code for implement endpoint behavior and attach it to all of your operations on all contracts ?

Answer (score 0):

There is so called [message interceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx) for wcf wherein you can intercept every incomming and outgoing request prior to the actual target operation. It's perfect implementation if you want to validate messages without annotating every operation. It's pretty easy to implement and hook up on your service.

This PENtest finding is not only resposibility of your service but also the app that will consume the result.

**Note :** Sometimes PENtest result could be false positive specialy if both app can handle input without harm :)